# import/export files from/to iCloud from our application

Tags: ios, icloud-api, mkicloudsync

I am working on `iCloud` api's for the first time. I want to import/export files (.doc,.pdf,.xls any kind of file) from/to iCloud through our application.

In our application there will be different kind of documents which the user should be able to save in cloud and, when user is using same application from different devices, all files which are saved in `iCloud` should fetch & show.